# How to move two collection view cells equally in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have two collection view cells and both of them should move simultaneously. How am I supposed to do it?

```
var nibName = UINib(nibName: "DateCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
self.DateCollectionView.registerNib(nibName, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: dateCellIdentifier)

var nibName1 = UINib(nibName: "AttendanceCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)

self.attendanceCollectionView.registerNib(nibName1, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: dateCellIdentifier1)


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

    if(collectionView == self.DateCollectionView ){
        return dateArr.count as Int
    }

    else {

        return 4 as Int
    }

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


    if(collectionView == self.DateCollectionView){

      var cella = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(dateCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DateCollectionViewCell


        cella.datelbl.text = dateArr.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! String


        return cella


    }
    else {

        var cellb = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(dateCellIdentifier1, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AttendanceCollectionViewCell
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What 's "move"(in should move simultaneously) mean? is it displayed?

Answer (score 0):

i am not able to comment on your post, thats why i am asking you this way, if you could describe your problem in more detail.

What i am seeing in your code is, that you have to `CollectionViews` (Date and attendance) and one controller implementation for that. The controller implements the `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` from the `UICollectionViewDataSource` protocol. So you have one controller to handle two different views. 
Is that what you want to do?

Can you also explain, whats already working or not working (Do some cells already get populated?, ...)

Comment: I have two collection views in the same view. It's just that when I scroll any one of the collection view vertically the other one should also move with respect to the first one.

Comment: The cells also get populated @Nguyen Hoan,@MarkusAtCvlabDotDe